# Is it possible to configure multiple picklist in Servicenow?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

How can we create a multi picklist in servicenow? There is no field type found like multiple choice as choice type is creating dropdown list. And also in some sites ,its suggested with the type **list Collector** but only **list** is found in available types.

Please suggest the field type to be used to create a multi picklist.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Check Box (values defined in variable) https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/newyork-it-service-management/page/product/service-catalog-management/reference/r_VariableTypes.html#d271134e161
2. List collector (elements are defined in a seperate table)
   https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/newyork-it-service-management/page/product/service-catalog-management/reference/r_VariableTypes.html#d271134e570